# Looping over array of arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays of objects that I want to loop over and print each element but for some reason, the loop is skipping some elements, and I understand why but I don't know what is the best way to fix it

Here is the code I used :

```
const test = [
  [
    {
      SESSION_ID: "200",
    },
    {
      SESSION_ID: "296",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      MICROFILM_REF_NUMBER: "9,52E+22",
    },
    {
      MICROFILM_REF_NUMBER: "9,52E+22",
    },
  ],
];

test.forEach((element, index) => {
  console.log(element[index].SESSION_ID);
  console.log(element[index].MICROFILM_REF_NUMBER);
});
```

The output I get is :

```
200
undefined
undefined
9,52E+22
```

The desired output is :

```
200
296
9,52E+22
9,52E+22
```

Comment: The `index` produced by the forEach is related to the top level arrays current `element`, but you are using it to access your inner array.

Comment: It will help you debug the issue if you assign unique values to each field. Consider what `element` and `index` are on each iteration.

Comment: You are iterating the parent array, but this parent array contains 2 child array which has object. You should be going inside each child array then iterate and print the object. Basically 2 loop will be required.

Comment: The thing is this is a very simplified version of the problem I have, the data you can see in `test` is JSON data from an API and I need to print everything out in a single table therefor am required to iterate over everything using one loop instead of 2

Comment: In that case you have oversimplified your objective and as a result will get inadequate answers. You must iterate inner arrays somewhere but if you want table columns that is different than logging to console and you probably need this data to another array

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned a table I believe you want something more along the lines of the following that maps your data to a `rows` array that can then easily be iterated to insert rows and cells into a table element

```js
const col_props = ['SESSION_ID', 'MICROFILM_REF_NUMBER'];

const rows = data[0].map((_, i) => {
  return data.map((arr, j) => arr[i][col_props[j]]);
});

console.log('Rows:',JSON.stringify(rows))

// for headings in demo
rows.unshift(col_props)

const table = document.querySelector('#myTable');

rows.forEach(arr => {
  const row = table.insertRow()
  arr.forEach(v => row.insertCell().textContent = v)
})
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1"></table>

<script>
const data=[[{SESSION_ID:"200"},{SESSION_ID:"296"}],[{MICROFILM_REF_NUMBER:"9,52E+22"},{MICROFILM_REF_NUMBER:"9,52E+22"}]];
</script>
```